# Heatmap texture according to object thickness

Tags: python, rendering, texturing, shaders, color

I made 3D surface reconstruction of a point cloud in meshlab and exported a obj file. I also have computed the thickness of the object and saved the data as "[x,y,thickness]" in a txt file, where "x" and "y" represent the position of the object. I import the obj file into blender and it is what it looks like:

[image]

I am a beginner to blender. I want to show the thickness of the object on the top surface of the object like a heatmap.

**---------------EDIT--------------**

I followed the answer of @alambre. However, I did not get the heatmap result. This is the blender file. (This problem is solved with the help of @blunder's comment under the first answer.)

[image]

Comment: There is a [Raycast](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/geometry/raycast.html) node in Geometry Nodes. It can calculate a hit distance but requires a source and a target geometry. I'm not sure if it works for this "pancake". If you already have "[x,y, thickness]" can't you create an image from this and project it on the object?

Comment: a rough preview you can get in edit mode, just open the 'Show Overlays' dropdown and enable 'Mesh Analysis' > Thickness... but for a nice greymap use cycles render with a volume material, a 'Volume Absortion' node is enough if you adjust density, could try to render a top ortho camera and use later as texture to feed a color ramp... but there are many ways to do it

Comment: also a quick Cycles material can be get with an Ambient Oclusion node set to Inside and a Color Ramp, feed an Emision shader and it's done... looks nice but I don't know if it's correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's a simple Geometry Nodes setup you can try, using raycast and a vertex color attribute to pass the data to the shader... how do want to calculate depth, it's using z vector here... play with map range to fit your mesh

[image: GN heatmap]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I followed your setup shown in the picture. However, I did not get the heatmap. I edit this question and upload the blender file. Can you help me find the error? Thanks a lot, I am still learning basic ideas of blender.

Comment: @kevinlee What happened to the *ColorRamp*?! It seems to be bugged. It creates white color but there is no white color at all. Reset it (Backspace), then choose red (FF0000) for the first color and green (00FF00) for the second. Then *HSV* and *Near* as options. This gives you the correct color pallet without white. But red, white (in the middle), green or blue, red, green look nice, too.

Because your pancake is really gigantic (40m) you have to adjust the values of the *Map Range* node (in the Geo Nodes). Try values of 14 and 60.7 =>  https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpYff.png

Comment: @Blunder Thanks a lot. It works! I will continue to learn blender.

Comment: you got pretty close, but what @Blunder says is right, thanks..! but also be sure to try a different setup without the GN nodes: use an 'Ambient Occlusion' node to feed the color ramp, enable 'Inside' and play with 'Distance' value, see you get a lot more of detail... but this setup only works in Cycles rendered view, and depth is sampled in all directions I think